# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages; in addition.jar and droidText2.0.jar

Tags: android

I am getting error

Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages; 
I am using 
addition.jar and droidText2.0.jar file for mail and pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's may be because of same class definition in multiple jar files. It can be resolved by removing one jar file from my lib folder. For more details you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584837/getting-unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-error-when-trying-to) also.

Comment: try deleting the android-support-v4.jar from your build path and lib folder if its present in your project