# Android app runtime error when ever running the program

Tags: android

What was the meaning of this code?

```
com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbiz/source_code/base64Coder/Base64Coder;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:772)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1046)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I am getting this error when ever I run the program.
please any one can help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783400/855950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file in bin/dexedLibs The same file exists in libs

Delete it in libs and it should work.

For me it was the android-support-v4.jar.

Hope this helps

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13783400/1143026)

Comment: there is point in front of my answer please click up arrow for adding 1 point