# Getting error in eclipse after adding paypal SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, paypal

i am new to android paypal integration. I got a jar file which i included it in the java build path and 
started to run the project but i am getting the new error

```
[2014-06-09 16:08:23 - Sandeep] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-06-09 16:08:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/paypal/android/sdk/A;
[2014-06-09 16:08:27 - Sandeep] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/paypal/android/sdk/A;
```

Can i know what is the mistake which i have committed after adding the `PaypalAndroidSDK`

Comment: There are so many possible solutions: check each one of them https://www.google.com/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed%3A+Unable+to+execute+dex%3A+Multiple+dex+files+define+Lcom%2Fpaypal%2Fandroid%2Fsdk%2FA%3B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs

Comment: Try these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688828/dex-loader-unable-to-execute-multiple-dex-files-define

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?  Providing your build scripts would be useful in debugging the problem.